# Does the word 'law' need to be capitalised?

Tags: grammar, capitalization

I'm currently writing my personal statement for my university application in the UK. Because I am applying for courses in law (or Law?), I naturally need to use the word 'law' in my statement. Note that this statement is sent to 5 universities so does not refer to a specific law course. I have used the word in the following sentences:

> The breadth of study for a **law** degree would provide me with the knowledge and experiences to determine the shape and direction of my career.

> My interest in **law** also stems from its interdisciplinary nature...

I feel that I don't need to capitalise 'law' here because it's talking about the subject in general, and so it's not a proper noun. However, my advisor has given me feedback and suggested I do need to. Thoughts?

Comment: @Laurel Yes, I think that is a similar case to mine that answers my question. Thank you.